# OSX differentiate applications with same name in PATH

Tags: macos, bash

In OSX, I have added a new path to `/etc/paths`. It is a path to a medical image viewer application known as `rview`.

It seems to clash with `vim` and on typing `rview` in `bash` it starts up `vim`.

But my question is more general, how do you differentiate applications with the same names included in `PATH`?

Comment: `which -a <name>` lists _all_ executables found in the `$PATH` by that name.

Comment: use the full path `/etc/paths/rview`

Comment: Order. The first `rview` found in the list of paths inside the file `/etc/paths` get executed first. Put your path at the very beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is evaluated in order; the first matching executable is run.

To edit this, you should change your user profile, not the system-wide configuration. You may have a line similar to this in your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Just add the path to your application before $PATH and it should work fine. If the line isn't there, create it.

And, if you really want to edit the system paths, just add yours at the top of `/etc/paths` instead of the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Annoyingly, even after doing this, `vim` runs instead of `rview`. Why does `vim` run on typing `rview` in the first place? Does it have an alias with that name?

Comment: `ls -lah /usr/bin/rview` will answer that for you. Are you sure you're setting your path correctly? Does `echo $PATH` show you what you're expecting i.e. your path first? You do need to exit from the shell and go back in again for changes in `.profile` to take effect.

Comment: Aha! so indeed there is a symbolic link to vim as doing `ls -lah /usr/bin/rview` revealed this `/usr/bin/rview -> vim`. By the way, `echo $PATH` does not show my path even though in my `~/.profile` I have this line now: `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:<my-application-path-here>:$PATH`

Comment: Thanks! Actually setting `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:<my-application-path-here>:$PATH` to `~/.bash_profile` helped!